# VS Code displays ($?) { g++ test.cpp -o test } ; if ($?) { .\test } in terminal

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

When I am running code in vscode, the text `if ($?) { g++ test.cpp -o test } ; if ($?) { .\\test }` always appears at the top of the terminal.
I don't know what it means.

Is this a problem, and if so, how do I fix it?

[image: image showing terminal with text in question]

The full text:

```
PS C:\Users\admin\OneDrive\Máy tính\Lập trình\Bài tập C++ TTA> cd "c:\Users\admin\OneDrive\Máy tính\Lập trình\Bài tập C++ TTA\Hàm\" ; if ($?) { g++ test.cpp -o test } ; if ($?) { .\test }
```

Comment: That's the command that's being run. It's expected and not a problem

Comment: Are you using the [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension? If so, this extension helps you generate a shell command that executes the `test.cpp` file.